# Value is not passing through Javascript it directly goes to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to pass a file and some text field and a drop down value to php in order to upload them all in a query in database. I'm validating the text field input in JavaScript to prevent giving any wrong input. But the problem is the values are not going through JavaScript all the time. So i've set the php file in form action. So now what is happening that, it is not checking individual text field input and not showing error. Rather goes  direct to the php. Now how can i resolve this

HTML

```
<form id="jobform" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2><b>Post your job</b></h2><br><br>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Job Position:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jName" placeholder="Enter job name" name="jName" required>
            <p id="jErr"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Job Salary:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sal" placeholder="Enter job salary" name="sal" required>
            <p id="salErr"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Job Type:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <select id="jType">
                    <option value="part-time">Part-Time</option>
                    <option value="full-time">Full-Time</option>
                    <option value="internship">Internship</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Job Location:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loc" placeholder="Enter job locations" name="loc" required>
            <p id="locErr"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Add some detailed description:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="u_file" value="u_file" type="file" name="u_file" size="5000000" multiple onchange="showname()"><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <br><button name="submitJob" id="submitJob" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="job_checker()">Submit</button>
        <p id="submitJobErr"></p></div>

</form>
```

JavaScript

```
signFlagj = 0;

function job_checker() {
    checkJobName();
    checkSalary();
    checkJobType();
    checkJobLoc();
    databasejobEntry();
}

function checkJobName() {

    jobnameET = document.getElementById("jName");
    var jobnameError = document.getElementById("jErr");

    jobname = jobnameET.value;
    console.log(jobname);

    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(jobname)){
        jobnameError.innerHTML = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        signFlagj = 1;
    }
    else {
        jobnameError.innerHTML = "";
    }

}

function checkSalary() {
    var salaryET = document.getElementById("sal");
    var salaryError = document.getElementById("salErr");

    jobsal = salaryET.value;
    console.log(jobsal);

    var regex = /^[1-9.,][0-9.,]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(jobsal)){
        salaryError.innerHTML = "Only numbers with or without comma or point is allowed";
        signFlagj = 1;
    }
    else {
        salaryError.innerHTML = "";
    }
}

function checkJobType() {
    var jobTypeET = document.getElementById("jType");
    jobType = jobTypeET.value;
    console.log(jobType);
}

function checkJobLoc() {

    var jobLocET = document.getElementById("loc");
    var locError = document.getElementById("locErr");

    jobLocation = jobLocET.value;
    console.log(jobLocation);

    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\s,'-]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(jobLocation)){
        locError.innerHTML = "Enter valid amount";
        signFlagj = 1;
    }
    else {
        locError.innerHTML = "";
    }

}


function showname() {
    jobFilename = document.getElementById('u_file');
    console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).name);
    console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).size);
    console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).type);
}
/*function toSubmit(){
    preventDefault();
      alert('I will not submit');
      return false;
   }*/

function databasejobEntry() {

    if(signFlagj==1) {
        console.log("fill up correctly!");
        alert("Sign up correctly!");
    window.location.href = "test.html";

    }
    else
    {
       // console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).name);
        console.log(jobname);

        var submitError = document.getElementById("submitJobErr");
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log(this.readyState);
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                console.log(this.status);
                var response = xhttp.responseText;
                console.log(response);
                submitError.innerHTML=response;
                alert(response);

                if(String(response.trim()) === "Success") {
                    alert("Successfully submitted :)");
                    var formdata = $('#jobform').serializeArray();
                    //alert(formdata);
                    document.getElementById("jobform").submit();
                    //window.location.href = "uploadJob.html";
                }
            }
        }
 xhttp.open("POST", "test.php?jobname="+jobname+"&jobType="+jobType+"&jobsal="+jobsal+"&jobLocation="+jobLocation+"&jobFilename="+jobFilename,true);
        //xhttp.open("POST", "three.php", true);


        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        //xhttp.open("POST", "test.php?jobname="+jobname+"&jobFilename="+jobFilename,true);
        xhttp.send();
}


}
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once('DBconnection.php');

//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//ini_set('log_errors', 1);

$val="";
$jobName = $_POST["jName"];
$jobType = $_POST["jType"];
$jobSalary = $_POST["sal"];
$jobLocation = $_POST["loc"];

echo "$jobName";
echo "$jobType";
echo "$jobSalary";
echo "$jobLocation";
//print_r($jobName);
echo"<br>";

//$u_file = $_FILES['jobFilename'];

$file_type = $_FILES['u_file']['type'];
$file_size = $_FILES['u_file']['size'];
$file_name = $_FILES['u_file']['name'];

//echo "$jobName";

print_r($file_name);
echo"<br>";
print_r($file_size);
echo"<br>";
print_r($file_type);
echo"<br>";
//echo "****************";

$currentdir = getcwd();
$targetfolder = $currentdir . "/testupload/";
// echo "****************";
print_r($targetfolder);

$targetfile = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['u_file']['name']) ;

print_r($targetfile);


//print_r($currentdir);
//echo "****************";

$uploadOk=1;

//print_r($file_type);

//echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['u_file']['name']). " is uploaded";


if ($file_type != "application/pdf" && $file_type != "image/png" && $file_type != "image/jpeg" && $file_type != "image/jpg") {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & PDF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}


if (file_exists($targetfile)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}


if($uploadOk==0){
echo "Problem in uploading file";
}

else {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['u_file']['tmp_name'], $targetfile)) {

$fileUpQueryjob = "INSERT INTO jobs (job_name,job_type,job_salary,job_location,job_filename) VALUES ('$jobName','$jobType','$jobSalary','$jobLocation','$file_name')";

$upJob = $db->query($fileUpQueryjob);
if ($upJob == true) {
$val = "Success";
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['u_file']['name']). " is uploaded";
}
else
echo "Error: " . $fileUpQueryjob . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
}
}

//echo "$val";
$db->close();
?>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: It might help if you post some code.

Comment: I have posted it.

Comment: @Israt Please mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that your button type is 'sumbit' and its taking preference over the onlick. So cleanest way, remove submit type, and manually submit after validation:

```
    <button name="submitJob" id="submitJob" class="btn btn-default" onClick="job_checker()">Submit</button>
```

Find your DOM form on your "validating" function, and submit it if all is ok:

```
function job_checker() {
    // just refactor all these functions to return "true" or "false"
    var isValid = checkJobName() &&
      checkSalary() &&
      checkJobType() &&
      checkJobLoc() &&
      databasejobEntry();
    // if all these validations went through,
    if (isValid) {
      document.querySelector('#jobForm').submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want that when it shows the errors for each field in corresponding inner HTML it would stay on that page showing the errors. But here it is switching the page with a blank page very quickly and i can't see those specific errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your javascript. Try this:

JAVASCRIPT

```
signFlagj = 0;

function job_checker() 
{
    checkJobName();
    checkSalary();
    checkJobType();
    checkJobLoc();
    databasejobEntry();
}

function checkJobName()
{
    var jobnameET = document.getElementById("jName");
    var jobnameError = document.getElementById("jErr");

    var jobname = jobnameET.value;
    console.log(jobname);

    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(jobname))
    {
        jobnameError.innerHTML = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        signFlagj = 1;
    }
    else jobnameError.innerHTML = "";
}

function checkSalary() 
{
    var salaryET = document.getElementById("sal");
    var salaryError = document.getElementById("salErr");

    var jobsal = salaryET.value;
    console.log(jobsal);

    var regex = /^[1-9.,][0-9.,]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(jobsal))
    {
        salaryError.innerHTML = "Only numbers with or without comma or point is allowed";
        signFlagj = 1;
}
else salaryError.innerHTML = "";

function checkJobType() 
{
    var jobTypeET = document.getElementById("jType");
    var jobType = jobTypeET.value;
    console.log(jobType);
}

function checkJobLoc()
{

    var jobLocET = document.getElementById("loc");
    var locError = document.getElementById("locErr");

    var jobLocation = jobLocET.value;
    console.log(jobLocation);

    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\s,'-]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(jobLocation))
    {
        locError.innerHTML = "Enter valid amount";
        signFlagj = 1;
    }
    else locError.innerHTML = "";
}

function showname()
{
    var jobFilename = document.getElementById('u_file');
    console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).name);
    console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).size);
    console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).type);
}

/*
  function toSubmit()
  {
    preventDefault();
      alert('I will not submit');
      return false;
  }
*/

function databasejobEntry()
{
    if(signFlagj==1)
    {
        console.log("fill up correctly!");
        alert("Sign up correctly!");
        window.location.href = "test.html";
    }
    else
    {
        // console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).name);
        console.log(jobname);

        var submitError = document.getElementById("submitJobErr");
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
        {
            console.log(this.readyState);
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                console.log(this.status);
                var response = xhttp.responseText;
                console.log(response);
                submitError.innerHTML=response;
                alert(response);

                if(String(response.trim()) === "Success")
                {
                    alert("Successfully submitted :)");
                    var formdata = $('#jobform').serializeArray();
                    //alert(formdata);
                    document.getElementById("jobform").submit();
                    //window.location.href = "uploadJob.html";
                }
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("POST", "test.php?jobname="+jobname+"&jobType="+jobType+"&jobsal="+jobsal+"&jobLocation="+jobLocation+"&jobFilename="+jobFilename,true);
        //xhttp.open("POST", "three.php", true);


        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        //xhttp.open("POST", "test.php?jobname="+jobname+"&jobFilename="+jobFilename,true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once('DBconnection.php');

// ...

// Since you are using a database connection consider using a function
// to escape strings like mysli_real_escape_string() if you are using MySQL
$jobName = $_POST["jName"];
$jobType = $_POST["jType"];
$jobSalary = $_POST["sal"];
$jobLocation = $_POST["loc"];

?>
```

Comment: I want that when it shows the errors for each field in corresponding inner HTML it would stay on that page showing the errors. But here it is switching the page with a blank page so quickly that i can't see properly those specific errors.